# Passport needed for flight within Canada

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I'm an international student in Canada (neither Canadian citizen, nor have PP card). I'm going to fly from YYZ international airport from Toronto to the international airport YUL in Montreal.

Do I need to hold my passport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a passport for domestic air travel, or another form of government-issued identification that includes your name, date of birth, and gender.

[The Department of Public Safety and Emergency Preparedness](https://www.publicsafety.gc.ca/cnt/ntnl-scrt/cntr-trrrsm/pssngr-prtct/dcmnts-en.aspx) lists what forms are accepted.

> **Required Documents for Domestic Travel**
>   According to the Secure Air Travel Regulations, the required identification to take a domestic flight is:
>
> - one piece of valid government-issued photo identification that shows the holder's name, date of birth and gender;
> - two pieces of valid government-issued identification, at least one of which shows the holder's name, date of birth and gender; or
> - a restricted area identity card. ***See note***
>
> For domestic flights within Canada, any valid identification that is issued by a recognized federal, provincial, or municipal government institution that has the required information may be used. Below are some examples of valid government-issued identification documents. Most would be sufficient on their own, while others may need to be supplemented with a second piece of valid government-issued identification:
>
> - passport
> - citizenship card
> - permanent-resident card
> - driver's license
> - provincial health card
> - provincial identity card
> - provincial or territorial government identification cards (GICs)
> - birth certificate
> - Record of Landing Form/Confirmation of Permanent Residence (IMM 5292)
> - immigration documents issued to foreign nationals (e.g., Work Permit, Study Permit, Visitor Record, Temporary Resident Permit, Refugee Approved Status)
> - Canadian military identification
> - federal police identification
> - federal, provincial or municipal government employee identification cards
> - Old Age Security (OAS) identification card
> - Certificate of Indian Status (Status Card) issued by Indian and Northern Affairs Canada (INAC)
> - Canada Border Services Agency NEXUS card
> - firearms license

**Note:**  [Restricted Area Identity Card (RAIC)](https://www.catsa-acsta.gc.ca/en/restricted-area-identity-card-raic). The RAIC system, created by CATSA in partnership with Transport Canada and airport authorities, uses iris and fingerprint biometric identifiers to allow non-passenger access to the restricted areas of airports.

Comment: Thanks. I have my Canadian driver's license. But what is "a restricted area identity card."?

Comment: I'll add it to the answer: the Restricted Area Identity Card (RAIC) system, created by CATSA in partnership with Transport Canada and airport authorities, uses iris and fingerprint biometric identifiers to allow non-passenger access to the restricted areas of airports.